# TFS build 2015 fails to trigger coded ui tests - part of continuous integration process

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

We have come across an issue where TFS build fails to trigger coded UI tests, based on how the Test Settings file is specified in the build definition.

We have been unable to get CodedUI test project to run. The goal is to have it run on a separate machine (virtual machine). We have configured the test controller and agent on the VM. We have also set it to run as interactive process. When we run build it partially succeeds and the following test error is reported

**The failure message returned is as below:**

> MsTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class ‘MVC_Test.MVCTest_CUI’ of assembly ‘C:\Builds\1\Test_COE\MVCAppFramework\bin\MVC_Test.dll’. Reason Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=12.0.0.0. Culture =neutral, PublickeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

**Setup / Environment Details:**

Visual studio 2015 ultimate

TFS server 2015

Agents for Visual studio 2015(Test Controller and Test Agents)

Test agent is installed as interactive process for Coded UI tests

Answer (score 1):

Your CodedUI tests were written in the 2013 version of VS.  I believe you have two options:

1. Install the [Agents for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750) on your test agent
2. Use binding redirects to automatically use the newer version as described in this [TFS 2010 to 2015 Upgrade: CodedUI Feature Test Builds](https://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/tfs-2010-to-2015-upgrade-codedui-feature-test-builds/) blog post

UPDATE

3. You could try upgrading your CodedUI DLLS to the VS2015 versions (14.0.0.0).

Comment: Thanks for response
We tried the two options you mentioned but issue is not yet resolved.
Is there any settings need to be changed in Build process I mean test settings for CodedUI tests.

Comment: No, we used option 2 when we moved from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 for several big CodedUI projects and it all worked for us..

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the dll libraries for Version 12.0 which provided by VS2013. Install VS2013 on the test agent and then retry.

Comment: To run tests on virtual machine through test agent I think we don't need to install VS 2013 on the virtual machine. 
**My main goal is: 
when I check in code in VS 2015 the build should trigger and MSbuild should complete the build and after that run CodedUI Tests present in the solution.
we are able to build the solution but couldn't able to run the CodedUI tests either through agents of VS 2015 or agents of VS2013**.